# Residuals from model missing interaction

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, interaction, residuals

In a plot of residuals against fitted values from a generalised linear model, I'm wondering what the plot would look like if an interaction was missing from the model. Can anyone simulate a model that is missing an interaction. Without the interaction included in the model, the residuals against fitted values plot shows clear patterns. With the interaction, the residuals against fitted values does not show any patterns.

Comment: What exactly is your question?